# windows remote login api using c#/c++

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi, remote-login

I want to write a program to login into remote machine using domain admin user credential and do following tasks

1. Get some system information like OS, IIS version, .net version etc
2. Transfer some files from remote to local machine and vice versa.

Is there any windows API to do this?

Task I am trying to do can done manually using remote desktop application, but I don't want to use GUI as I would like to automate this, to get machine info periodically from our environment and display in a Dashboard.

Comment: There are API's but the services that host them are not enabled by default and will need to be manually started, will that be a problem.

Comment: I would like to use same APIs that are used by "Remote Desktop" as everything is set-up.

Comment: Well, the API's for remote desktop do not provide a way to get that information without actually getting a full remote desktop session. So that means on non server versions of windows you will disconnect people using the computer as it can only have one person logged in at a time. Is that what you want?

Comment: yes that's fine. ppl should not be keep connected to server and automated application wouldn't run every day.

Answer (score 1):

you can use winrm
and automate it using powershell
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

here is a vb [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384423(v=vs.85).aspx) (you can use the same COM objects in c#)

```
Const RemoteComputer = "ComputerName.domain.com"
Set objWsman = CreateObject("Wsman.Automation")
Set objConnectionOptions = objWsman.CreateConnectionOptions
objConnectionOptions.UserName = "Username"
objConnectionOptions.Password = "Password"
iFlags = objWsman.SessionFlagUseKerberos Or _
  objWsman.SessionFlagCredUserNamePassword
Set objSession = objWsman.CreateSession("https://" & RemoteComputer, _
  iFlags, objConnectionOptions)
strResource = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/" & _
  "wmi/root/cimv2/Win32_OperatingSystem"
Set objResponse = objSession.Enumerate(strResource)

While Not objResponse.AtEndOfStream
    DisplayOutput(objResponse.ReadItem) 
Wend

'****************************************************
' Displays WinRM XML message using built-in XSL
'****************************************************
Sub DisplayOutput(strWinRMXml)
    Dim xmlFile, xslFile
    Set xmlFile = CreateObject("MSXml2.DOMDocument.3.0") 
    Set xslFile = CreateObject("MSXml2.DOMDocument.3.0")
    xmlFile.LoadXml(strWinRMXml)
    xslFile.Load("WsmTxt.xsl")
    Wscript.Echo xmlFile.TransformNode(xslFile) 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks rravuri, to use winrm I will have to enable/configure winrm in each remote server (https://support.microsoft.com/kb/555966/en-us). my point was if I can login remotely using "Remote desktop" why can't I use same API from my own application? if I can use same API to interact with remote server I don't have any dependency on other APIs/have to enable/disable them.